# Show properties values in views in Spring MVC

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, view

I'm struggling to make something veeery simple work. Everything I really need to do is to write a property value in a view, i.e.:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    ...
    <base href="${properties.config.baseurl}" />
    ...
</head>
<body>
...
</body>
</html>
```

My Spring MVC configuration (relevant bit):

```
<bean id="properties" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertiesFactoryBean">
    <property name="locations">
        <list><value>/WEB-INF/config.properties</value></list>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/" />
    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    <property name="exposedContextBeanNames">
        <list><value>properties</value></list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

/WEB-INF/config.properties file:

```
config.baseurl = http://localhost:8080/
```

The view doesn't display anything at all (i.e. `<base href="" />`), can anyone explain to me why?

Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to use

```
${properties['config.baseurl']}
```

rather than

```
${properties.config.baseurl}
```

Otherwise it will try to navigate `config.baseurl` like a bean path, rather than as a string literal.

Comment: Shouldn't `<c:out />` be used as well?

Comment: @ŁukaszBachman: Not necessarily. All that does is XML-escape the output.